# Remove duplicate x-axis and y-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to avoid duplicate axis values in a combined graph plot?

The one plotted using ggplot is given below (original.png) and the preferred output is attached  at the bottom (Preferred.png).

[![Original.png][1]][1]

```
Plot_T_1 <- ggplot(T_1, aes(x = Season, y = Ter_1,fill=Season,color = Season)) +
  geom_violin(adjust=0.75, position = "dodge", alpha = 0.7,fill = "transparent") + #adjust 0.75 changes the visual shape of the violin
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.05, position = position_dodge(0.75), color = "black", alpha = 0) + #alpha 0 fully transparent
  geom_text(data=count_Ter_1,aes(x = as.factor(Season), y = 0, label = paste("N =", n)))+
  ggtitle("Ter_1") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5), breaks = seq(0, 0.5, by = 0.1))+
  guides(fill = FALSE)

Plot_T_2 <- ggplot(T_2, aes(x = Season, y = Ter_2,fill=Season,color = Season)) +
  geom_violin(adjust=0.75, position = "dodge", alpha = 0.7,fill = "transparent") + #adjust 0.75 changes the visual shape of the violin
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.05, position = position_dodge(0.75), color = "black", alpha = 0) + #alpha 0 fully transparent
  geom_text(data=count_Ter_2,aes(x = as.factor(Season), y = 0, label = paste("N =", n)))+
  ggtitle("Ter_2") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5), breaks = seq(0, 0.5, by = 0.1))+
  guides(fill = FALSE)

Plot_T_3 <- ggplot(T_3, aes(x = Season, y = Ter_3,fill=Season,color = Season)) +
  geom_violin(adjust=0.75, position = "dodge", alpha = 0.7,fill = "transparent") + #adjust 0.75 changes the visual shape of the violin
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.05, position = position_dodge(0.75), color = "black", alpha = 0) + #alpha 0 fully transparent
  geom_text(data=count_Ter_3,aes(x = as.factor(Season), y = 0, label = paste("N =", n)))+
  ggtitle("Ter_3") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5), breaks = seq(0, 0.5, by = 0.1))+
  guides(fill = FALSE)

Plot_T_4 <- ggplot(T_4, aes(x = Season, y = Ter_4,fill=Season,color = Season)) +
  geom_violin(adjust=0.75, position = "dodge", alpha = 0.7,fill = "transparent") + #adjust 0.75 changes the visual shape of the violin
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.05, position = position_dodge(0.75), color = "black", alpha = 0) + #alpha 0 fully transparent
  geom_text(data=count_Ter_4,aes(x = as.factor(Season), y = 0, label = paste("N =", n)))+
  ggtitle("Ter_4") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5), breaks = seq(0, 0.5, by = 0.1))+
  guides(fill = FALSE)


library(patchwork)

combined_plot <- Plot_T_1+ Plot_T_2+Plot_T_3+ Plot_T_4 + 
  plot_layout(nrow = 2, guides = "collect") + 
  plot_annotation(title = "Combined Plot")

print(combined_plot)
```

[![Preferred.png][2]][2]

Appreciate inputs.

Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pygCk.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDgOP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to do this if all your data can be in the same dataframe because you can leverage the facet plotting feature to subset your data based on T_x (i.e., create your panels) and otherwise handle everything in one (layered) command.

You don't provide any data, so here is an example using the [diamonds dataset](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/diamonds.html) that is available with ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Subset to keep only four colors, analogous to your "T_x"
subset_diamonds <- diamonds[diamonds$color %in% c("E", "I", "J", "H"), ]

# Plotting with facet wrap on the color
p <- ggplot(subset_diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price, color = cut)) +
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1, outlier.shape = NA, color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~ color, nrow = 2, ncol = 2) +
  labs(title = "Price Distribution by Cut for Different Diamond Colors") +
  xlab("Cut") +
  ylab("Price") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to play around with adding these theme elements to your individual plots:

```
theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank())

theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```